# svelte + express (without sapper) - how to send props/communicate with the server?

Tags: express, svelte

I am coding a little website to be my homepage.
So far I managed to do what I wanted with **express and handlebars templates** but I am doing this website to test my boundaries, and I lack using a **frontend framework** and working with web **components**.

so for the sake of challenge and learning, I settled on [**svelte**](https://svelte.dev/)
*which is not exactly a framework, I read, but is a delight to write with and seems very promising on the performance side.*

The problem is I want to **keep the hand on my website**, and **sapper**, the full framework that comes with svelte, is a bit too much of a **black box** for me.
*(you put this file here and that file there,

compile with this complex configuration you shouldn't touch

and BOOM you got routes)*

What I would like is to use **express to manage the routes** and then render the svelte app, either with a different page/app for a route, or the same app with different variables.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?
I considered using **sessions** or a **socket**, but I have no idea of how to listen to this client-side and the documentation/articles about svelte are sparse and all talk about sapper.

*here are a few lines of code I wrote in a test app. I know it's not the way you do it but it was for curiosity's sake*

```js
// --------------server.js
// ...
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'))
// Using a view engine on TOP of svelte 
// is certainly a bad choice

app.use(express.static('app/public'))
// to make the svelte compiled .js and .css available

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home', {user:true}) 
  // I tried to send props like this
  // it did not get the props in svelte, 
  // but what I found is that svelte ADDS itself to the page
  // and does not remove the HBS code, event though it is in the target container
})
```

---

#### edit

I will finally use sapper, thank you for the advices...
I really would like them to implement some sort of svelte middleware that allows to render/serve pages individually (once they are build of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it like that, splitting your web application into several independent svelte apps that are served from express, then you need to keep the (web-)application wide state on the backend or keep it in the local storage on the browser. You can't use the states provided by sveltes store (writeable, etc), because that's in-memory and destroyed whenever you navigate to a new page (via express).

If sapper is to much magic but you want to keep running a single-page-app, have a look at [svelte-spa-router](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router). That isn't configuration based.

Comment: thank you,  svelte-spa-router seems easier to use than sapper. I'll give it a try

Comment: ... but I really want to concile express routing and svelte client... maybe I should make a full frontend server that comunicates with my express backend... but if avoidable I would rather not to

Comment: Technically, it works. But you'll need one svelte app for each page. rollup can support that, btw, you can define an array of configurations which would be one for each svelte page. I'd try it with a simple app, like a homepage, an about page and a third one and check if that 'feels ok' or hurts. (I expect that it hurts ;) )

Comment: I looked at sapper's compiled server and it seems to send the template.html with scripts inserted in script tags for each page (in JavaScript strings ...) I guess it would be possible to create some middleware that would render a page by loading the .js bundles and insert it into the template.html, feels dirty but it's the way sapper seems to do it